# Equivalent function in HANA DB for json_object

Tags: sql, hana

I would like to return the query results into json format in HANA DB.

There is a json_object function in oracle to achieve this requirement, but I am not seeing any function in HANA.
Does anyone knows if this kind of function exists in HANA
For example:

Table Author contains non-json data as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------
|  firstName        |   lastName            |
---------------------------------------------
|  Paulo            |   Coelho              |
|  George           |   Orwell              |
---------------------------------------------
```

write a select statement to return result as json.
In Oracle it can be returned using query:

```
SELECT json_object(
  KEY 'firstName' VALUE author.first_name, 
  KEY 'lastName'  VALUE author.last_name
)
FROM author
```

Output looks like this:

```
---------------------------------------------
| json_array                                 |
---------------------------------------------
| {"firstName":"Paulo","lastName":"Coelho"}  | 
| {"firstName":"George","lastName":"Orwell"} |
----------------------------------------------
```

Does anyone knows query or function in HANA to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the already mentioned function in SAP HANA too

```
JSON_QUERY (
 <JSON_API_common_syntax>
 [ <JSON_output_clause> ]
 [ <JSON_query_wrapper_behavior> ]
 [ <JSON_query_empty_behavior> ON EMPTY ]
 [ <JSON_query_error_behavior> ON ERROR ]
  )
```

[research](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.01/en-US/3126ea33d50d42d19517a08fe22ec5a1.html)

Comment: Hi Vivek,
I believe JSON_QUERY function is to filter/retrieve data where table contains json values. But can it be used to convert non json data to json?

I have updated the question, so that its more clear.

Thank you

Comment: we cant do it in HANA, there is no functionality to achieve it via SQL query itself.. If you want it to be the result you may explore into XSJS concepts.

Answer (score 0):

For 2.0 SP04 and above there's a `for json` addition to the [`select` statement](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.04/en-US/20fcf24075191014a89e9dc7b8408b26.html). As documentation says, it is only permitted in subqueries, so you need to select individual columns in subselect (if you need a result set of JSON objects) of generate a JSON array as a single scalar result. Column names are inherited from subquery aliases.

Case 1:

```
with a as (
  select 'AAA' as field1, 'Value 1' as val from dummy union all
  select 'BBB' as field1, 'Value 2' as val from dummy
)
select
  /*Use correlated subquery with single row*/
  json_value((select a.field1, a.val from dummy for json), '$[0]') as res
from a
```

Or more effort to type-in, but less structure-dependent:

```
with a as (
  select 'AAA' as field1, 'Value 1' as val from dummy union all
  select 'BBB' as field1, 'Value 2' as val from dummy
)
, json_source as (
  /*Intermediate query to use as correlation source in JSON_TABLE*/
  select (select * from a for json) as tmp_json
  from dummy
)
select json_parsed.*
from json_source,
  json_table(
  json_source.tmp_json
  /*Access individual items*/
  , '$[*]'
  columns (
    res nvarchar(1000) format json path '$'
  )
) as json_parsed
```

Both return:

| RES |
| --- |
| {"FIELD1":"AAA","VAL":"Value 1"} |
| {"FIELD1":"BBB","VAL":"Value 2"} |

Or as a scalar query returning JSON array (Case 2):

```
with a as (
  select 'AAA' as field1, 'Value 1' as val from dummy union all
  select 'BBB' as field1, 'Value 2' as val from dummy
)
select *
from (select * from a for json)
```

| JSONRESULT |
| --- |
| [{"FIELD1":"AAA","VAL":"Value 1"},{"FIELD1":"BBB","VAL":"Value 2"}] |