# Equivalent function in HANA DB for json_object - case of Subqueries

Tags: sql, json, hana

Following on Raghav question : [Equivalent function in HANA DB for json_object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68790958/equivalent-function-in-hana-db-for-json-object) and great answers from [vivekanandasr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16651959/vivekanandasr) and [astentx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2778710/astentx), my subsequent question is :

**How to use "for JSON" with SAP Hana 2.0 when considering a header table and a line table ?**

**Problem** : When a nested query or a scalar subquery is used with "for JSON" in SAP HANA, the query engine interprets the result of the subquery as text.

*for example, with a table F for invoices header and a table F1 for invoices lines :*

```
SELECT F."DocNum" , F."DocDate",

   (SELECT "ItemCode", "Quantity"
    FROM INV1 F1 WHERE F."DocEntry" = F1."DocEntry" FOR JSON )
       AS "DocumentLines"

FROM OINV F
WHERE F."DocEntry" = 17216
FOR JSON ( 'arraywrap'='no');
```

is supposed to return something like :

```
{
    "DocDate":"2022-04-30"
    ,"DocNum":117121
    ,"DocumentLines":
       [{"ItemCode":"ITEM1", "Quantity":10}
        ,{"ItemCode":"ITEM2","Quantity":20}]
}
```

SAP Hana returns :

```
{
    "DocDate":"2022-04-30"
    ,"DocNum":117121
    ,"DocumentLines":"[{\"ItemCode\":\"ITEM1\",\"Quantity\":10},   {\"ItemCode\":\"ITEM2\",\"Quantity\":20}]"
}
```

**2 consequences :**

the " sign is escaped with \"

the array is considered as text and the brackets are surrounded with "

... and the resulting Json is not correct ...

The equivalent on MSSQL seems to work with "for json auto" but i don't know how to make it works with SAP Hana ?

Comment: Is the nested array a mandatory requirement for your result set? Otherwise you could generate a flat json with 4 attributes by using a join instead of a sub-select.

Comment: Unfortunately yes, the goal is to obtain a hierarchically structured json that represents the oData object of, for example, an invoice, to POST it into the ERP rest API

Comment: @GBoucher , did you manage to get this to work as intended (thus without escaped quotes in nested JSON)?